# D3.js adding draggable circles not working when adding single

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geometry

I am following this example:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

the thing I can't understand is how I can possibly add new circles when a button is clicked, for example:

```
d3.tsv("dots.tsv", dottype, function (error, dots) {
    container.append("g")
                .attr("class", "dot")
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(dots)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("r", 5)
                .attr("cx", function (d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                })
                .call(drag);
        });

        function dottype(d) {
            d.x = +d.x;
            d.y = +d.y;
            return d;
        }
self.addNode = function () {
            container.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'dot')
                .append('circle')
                .attr('r', 35)
                .attr('cx', (i * 100) + cx)
                .attr('cy', (i * 100) + cy)
                //.style('fill', 'purple')
                .call(drag);
            i++;
        };
```

The first part is the same as the example, I then created a function to add a single circle inside the container, the problem is that when I drag the new added circle I can move only the external G element, thus moving every other circle together.

I can't understand why, as the functions are the same (I removed even the style 'fill' to be sure)

Comment: Can you share the research you've done on how to add new nodes to a d3 layout? Ex: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795. You have to update your graph data. What you are doing is only adding an html element to your container element and will be gone after d3 renders your new svg.

Comment: I exactly did what you said, I was not aware of a partiuclar layout, because I didn't see any d3 function, just the tsv to read the data.
Maybe I am missing something? Am I completely wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving your layout a data in `.data(dots)` but when you are adding a node in your addNode function, the layout is unaware of this new data. What you want is to add/push the new node data to your data array(dots) and recall the drawing function.

Therefore, you should cut the code under d3.tsv into a function to call it again when you update the data.

Comment: If you can put up a fiddle or plunkr, we can help in more detail.

Comment: I now save my data into a var, that is updated (for example `dots.push` ) and then selectAll.enter.append (re-rendered)